# Explanation of line

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading editorial in Times Of India and read these two lines:

This October as many as 3.2 million Indian debit cards were reported to have been compromised in a big breach of financial data. Even as that investigation continues, demonetisation has sent e-banking and e-wallets on the up and up with inadequate digital literacy to cope with this shift.

I dont understand following lines:

What does have been compromised mean actually ?The writer talks about some investigation. What is the investigation ?

The article is titled 'Check cyber crim', dated, 13 Dec(IST) at :http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-editorials/check-cyber-crime-as-india-goes-digital-fast-its-vulnerabilities-also-grow-at-a-worrying-pace/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Whilst it is not strictly against the rules, please refrain from posting the same question in this forum and also in EL&U, if only for the reason that it is useful to have all answers (and comments) in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

> What does have been compromised mean actually?

This means that the confidential information pertaining to the hacked debit cards fell into the hands of unauthorized personnel.

> The writer talks about some investigation. What is the investigation?

This investigation is the one ordered by the Government (or some competent authority) to look into as to how such a breach (hack) took place.

**EDIT:**

> "in a big breach of financial data"

simply refers to the possible unauthorized access (referred to as a breach) of the (financial) data (such as account details, passwords, CVV numbers, etc.) pertaining to those 3.2 million debit cards.